# Why isn't it possible to make a tuple which contains a tuple and a unique_ptr as values in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, unique-ptr, stdtuple

Putting an `std::unique_ptr` inside an `std::tuple` works without any issues, but when the `tuple` contains another `tuple` together with a `unique_ptr` as elements, then the compiler throws an error.
Example:

```
    std::tuple<int, std::unique_ptr<Entity>> tupleA {1, std::move(new Entity)};

    //this line throws an error!
    std::tuple<std::tuple<int, int>, std::unique_ptr<Entity>> tupleB {{1, 1}, std::move(new Entity)};
```

The second line, creating the `tupleB` is throwing the following error:

```
        error: no matching constructor for initialization of ´std::tuple<std::tuple<int, int>,std::unique_ptr<Entity>>´
        note: candidate constructor template not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to ´std::allocator_arg_t´
```

**What exactly is the Problem here?**

Comment: Try `std::tuple<int, int>{1, 1}` in the constructor instead

Comment: should be: `auto tupleB = std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(1, 1), std::make_unique<Entity>());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Change your code so it reads

```
std::tuple<std::tuple<int, int>, std::unique_ptr<Derived>> tupleB{std::make_tuple(1,1), std::move(new Derived)};
```

**Details**

Your compiler tells you what is wrong. It says (MSVC in this case)

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::tuplestd::tuple<int,int,std::unique_ptr<Derived,std::default_delete>>'

So instead of using the initializer list go like this

```
std::tuple<std::tuple<int, int>, std::unique_ptr<Derived>> tupleB{std::make_tuple(1,1), std::move(new Derived)};
```

The issue is the following:

When a container is initialized with values within braces, like { 1, 1}, this  is deduced to type `std::initializer_lists<const char *>`. In turn the compiler looks for a container constructor which takes an initializer list as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`std::forward_as_tuple(1, 1)` instead of `{1, 1}` should work.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use initializer list to initialize a tuple, you have to use `std::make_tuple` like below:

```
std::tuple<std::tuple<int, int>, std::unique_ptr<Entity>> tupleB {std::make_tuple<int, int>(1, 1), std::move(new Entity)};
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `{1, 1}` use `std::make_tuple(1, 1)`